# Django 1.8.17 django-debug-toolbar Logging panel

Tags: python, django, logging, django-debug-toolbar

I have Django 1.8.17 and I can see django-debug-toolbar from my dashboard.
I'd like to be able to log messages in Logging panel\

**setting.py**

```
import logging

# create logger
logger = logging.getLogger('simple_example')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# create console handler and set level to debug
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# create formatter
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

# add formatter to ch
ch.setFormatter(formatter)

# add ch to logger
logger.addHandler(ch)

# 'application' code
logger.debug('debug message')
logger.info('info message')
logger.warn('warn message')
logger.error('error message')
logger.critical('critical message')
```

I can see output in Terminal console but not in Logging panel
Any clue?